# printing all tokens after 2nd token in a batch script

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I am looking for a cleaner way to do this. I'm pretty sure it's wrong even though it kind of works. Basically I'm taking output like this from a file (temp.txt):

```
    Host Name:                 IBM-3J93A46MRS5
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
    OS Version:                6.1.7631 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
    Registered Owner:          IAMADMIN
    Original Install Date:     2011-12-15, 10:56:07 AM
    System Boot Time:          2013-05-27, 9:55:36 AM
    System Manufacturer:       DELL
    System Model:              4009BF7
    Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
    Total Physical Memory:     16,316 MB
    Available Physical Memory: 11,356 MB
```

And trying to get JUST the 2nd column of data into a variable. Depending on if I want it or not. I'm using Findstr to weed out.

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    systeminfo > temp.txt
    set "tmp_result_file=temp.txt"

    for /f "tokens=3-7 delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"OS Name:" %tmp_result_file%') do set "OSNAME=%%i %%j %%k %%l"
    for /f "tokens=3-10 delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /V /C:"BIOS Version:" %tmp_result_file%^|FIND /I "OS Version:"') do set "OSVER=%%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p"
    for /f "tokens=4-7 delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Original Install Date:" %tmp_result_file%') do set "INSTDATE=%%i %%j %%k %%l"
    for /f "tokens=3-7 delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"System Manufacturer:" %tmp_result_file%') do set "SYSMFG=%%i %%j %%k %%l"
    for /f "tokens=3-7 delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"System Model:" %tmp_result_file%') do   set "SYSMDL=%%i %%j %%k %%l"

    echo.
    echo Operating System      : %OSNAME% , %OSVER% 
    echo Original Install Date : %INSTDATE%
    echo Model Information     : %SYSMFG% %SYSMDL%
```

I don't like that I am using tokens so precisely, I just need everything after the search value.

Comment: Use a wildcard in the tokens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for delayed expansion, a temp file, or FINDSTR, and certainly no need to count space delimited tokens. You just need to set the correct DELIMS and TOKENS options. The first FOR /F processes the output of `systeminfo` and parses each line into a name and value. The second FOR /F strips the leading white space from each value. All that is left is a series of IF statements to test each name and set the desired variable as appropriate.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('systeminfo') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%S in ("%%B") do (
    if "%%A"=="OS Name" set "OSNAME=%%S"
    if "%%A"=="OS Version" set "OSVER=%%S"
    if "%%A"=="Original Install Date" set "INSTDATE=%%S"
    if "%%A"=="System Manufacturer" set "SYSMFG=%%S"
    if "%%A"=="System Model" set "SYSMDL=%%S"
  )
)

echo(
echo Operating System      : %OSNAME%, %OSVER%
echo Original Install Date : %INSTDATE%
echo Model Information     : %SYSMFG% %SYSMDL%
```

If you want to capture more values, it might be desirable to specify the search string:variable name pairs using strings and add some extra FOR loops to process each test as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('systeminfo') do for %%S in (
  "OS Name:OSNAME"
  "OS Version:OSVER"
  "Original Install Date:INSTDATE"
  "System Manufacturer:SYSMFG"
  "System Model:SYSMDL"
) do for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%a in ("%%~S") do if %%A==%%a (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%s in ("%%B") do set "%%b=%%s"
)

echo(
echo Operating System      : %OSNAME%, %OSVER%
echo Original Install Date : %INSTDATE%
echo Model Information     : %SYSMFG% %SYSMDL%
```

Comment: I love loops, but so many loops in a narrow space make me feel giddy. :)

Comment: Thank you, so SO much better than what I had.  Should I add "if not defined OSNAME set "OSNAME=N/A"" to make sure it is set to something?

Comment: @MikeQ - That is totally up to you and your requirements. You could simply initialize the values before the first FOR loop, then you don't need IF.

Comment: @djangofan - My original answer was tested and functioned exactly as intended, capturing a series of variables and producing output exactly as the OP requested. Your edit modified the output significantly, and obfuscated the point I was trying to make with the 2nd code snippet. I rolled the edits back to the original version.

Answer (score 5):

goi'n the easy way  `:-)`

```
@echo OFF &setlocal
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN (file) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ("%%j") DO SET "$%%i=%%a"
)
SET "$"
echo Windows version: %$OS Name%
```

..output is:

```
$Available Physical Memory=11,356 MB
$Host Name=IBM-3J93A46MRS5
$Original Install Date=2011-12-15, 10:56:07 AM
$OS Configuration=Standalone Workstation
$OS Name=Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
$OS Version=6.1.7631 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
$Registered Owner=IAMADMIN
$System Boot Time=2013-05-27, 9:55:36 AM
$System Manufacturer=DELL
$System Model=4009BF7
$Time Zone=(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
$Total Physical Memory=16,316 MB
Windows version: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
```

Comment: This is awesome solution! The only thing I've changed when parsing some config file, was adding some prefix to variable names, to be sure that there is no conflict with some already existing variables in the code. `DO SET "$AUTOPARSED_%%i=%%a"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get everything else after the 3rd token, simply use a wildcard in the token value as follows:-

```
for /f "tokens=3* delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"OS Name:" %tmp_result_file%') do set "OSNAME=%%i"
```

should display

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
```